# What is the external URL for this <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I'm using a form that has 3 parts, login, forgot password and registration. The initial view is the login form, but can be changed to the forgot password or registration form, which replaces the initial view by using JS.

I'm looking to post back to the page if validation isn't met. This seems to be working fine, and the field repopulates itself. However I can't get the right form to load when posted back.

For example, if the user is filling out the forgot password form, and fills in an invalid email address, the message at the top of the form will be correct, however the form that will appear is the default login form. Once the user clicks on the forgot password button, JS kicks it over to the forgot password form, and has the users invalid email address re-populated. Each form has a unique "form_type" hidden variable to differentiate between the three, so I can use this to check then load the right one. Ideally I would like to keep this as 1 page and use JS to swap between the three if possible.

I don't know how to get it to load the right form once posted back. It's using the below code to change between the forms. How do I link to the right form when posting back.

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="forget-password">
<a href="javascript:;" id="register-btn">
```

I'm not good with JS at all, and I think this is the issue. The front end and JS is all created by a third party, it's "Metronic" theme. Let me know if I need to include any JS. If it makes a difference, although the logic should be the same, I'm using codeigniter too.

**EDIT** All the functionality to swap between the forms is there, I just need it to POST back to the right form. This is what I have so far, if you click on the forgot password and enter an email address that is longer than 5 characters, you'll see what I mean. I obviously didn't ask this very well...

Once the user submits, and the form is posted back with errors, I need right form to pop up, rather than the default for the page. The  tags above are the links used to swap between the different forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try on posting back to view also bring one extra variable say **'show_form'**

in that show_form have you form id and based on that do jquery hide/show method

like `$('#' + show_form).show()` and other 2 hide.

you can try this.

Comment: Thanks, despite the poorly worded question, this ended up being the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking.
Do you need to have 3 forms in the same page and swap between them with JS?

If so, give each of the forms a unique ID and have 2 forms with display: none. then all you have to do (assuming you do not want to use jQuery) is just to change the style.

HTML:

```
<form id="first_form" class="form-visible">
    ...
</form>

<form id="second_form" class="form-gone">
    ...
</form>

<form id="third_form" class="form-gone">
    ...
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.form-visible
{
    display: inline;
}

.form-visible
{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function swapForms(id)
{
    Swap-between-forms        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

differentiate the form with some variable . for example after submission form you can post back errors in variable name like if the submitted form is forgot password means define the variable name is $forgot like that. in view file check if(isset($forgot)) then set it's style as display block .